# Error:property not available on the object angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to access property from the object but i got error. Below is the json format i got from the server.Below is my json.

```js
{
"result": false,
"messages": "welcome",
"data": [
{
"name": "siva",
"category": true,
"count": 3
}
]
}
```

and below is my code to get property from the object

```js
this.dataService.getdata()
.subscribe(data => this.result = data['data'],
error => this.errorMsg = error
);
```

please guide my where i did a mistake. i want to get the data property from the json.
[image]

after changing data.data to data['data'] i got error like below
[image]

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: property not available on the object

Comment: Will you please show the code for dataService.getdata ?

Comment: when i tried code -- data => this.result = data.data i got error

Comment: getdata() {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.url);
  }

Comment: Successfully i got json, but i try to get property data from the json i got error

Comment: @Ramu Try to read the data.data as data['data']. And make sure your response is JSON object, not a string. If it's a string parse it.

Comment: Sure Niral, how to check and how to parse tell me please

Comment: Niral ,after changing code  showing the error in console like attached screen shot

Comment: @Ramu refer this demo link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-demo-psycbg-fetch-json-from-http-get-ox8vqv?file=app/DataService.service.ts

Comment: hrdkisback, please mention as answer, your code is working

Answer (score 0):

Add `map` to the `return` value of `getdata` :

```
return this.httpClient.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, i got response. but i want to get property array from the json. like below :  [
{
"name": "siva",
"category": true,
"count": 3
}
]

Comment: @Ramu , will you please also show the screenshot of error ?

Comment: AFAIK in Angular 5 there is no need to do `res.json()`.

Comment: Vivek , i have attached screen-shot please check.

Comment: what the output of `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Vivek, i have attached screen-shot please check